# Copiar diretório inteiro com python

Tags: python, automatização

Olá, gostaria de copiar um diretório inteiro utilizando o python, pois tenho uma base de site pronta e toda vez que vou criar um novo projeto eu tenho que ficar movendo os arquivos para uma nova pasta.
Gostaria de fazer isso, sem mover esses arquivos e sim dar um ctrl-c neles e ctrl-v na pasta destino.

Seria possível fazer isso com python?

Comment: O que você tentou até agora ? Podes mostrar um pouco do seu código ?

Comment: Não, na verdade eu só vi alguns exemplos aqui dentro do stack, mas não cheguei a criar nada.

Comment: Infelizmente os exemplos aqui eram somente para mover arquivos de dentro dos diretórios para outro, mas nunca uma pasta inteira.

Comment: Leia sobre o módulo [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#module-shutil).

Comment: Vlw mesmo cara. Vou tentar encontrar a solução aqui. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#module-shutil)

Veja que ela tem um aviso sobre a incapacidade de copiar metadados, possivelmente você encontrará outros problemas de acordo com o seu SO.

A melhor solução seria escrever o script de cópia em Bash no linux ou shell (cmd) no windows e chamar a rotina de dentro do Python usando [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Pode ser tão simples quanto:

```
import subprocess
in_dir = #"pasta a copiar"
out_dir = #"local de destino"
rotina = ["cp",in_dir,out_dir] # exemplo usando Bash
processo = subprocess.run(rotina)
```

Comment: Legal cara, vlw mesmo. Com certeza irei tentar reproduzir essa ideia. Vlw

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta funcionou, marca como aceita.